# pygame running in cygwin - no available video device?

Tags: python, cygwin, sdl, pygame

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with Cygwin version:

```
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10 i686 Cygwin
```

I installed pygame version 1.9.1-3 using cygwinports. So the cygwin setup automatically installed all my dependencies including libsdl version 1.2.14-1.

I tried testing out a game written in pygame and I'm getting this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 959, in <module>
    main()
  File "Main.py", line 25, in main
    windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720), DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.error: No available video device
```

I searched this error online and many people said to try setting SDL_VIDEODRIVER to "windib". I have done so and actually printed the environment variable in the python game just to make sure it was being set properly and it is in fact "windib".

So I am pretty lost on what else to try; is there a dependency I'm yet missing?

I believe this may be related to a cygwin update I performed which now requires X windows for almost all GUI and graphical applications. I will try making this an  X window and see what happens.

Comment: There are pygame binaries available for 64-bit Windows at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame . Any reason you're trying to go through the extra layer of Cygwin?

Comment: No reason in particular, just figured it should work seeing as it's in cygwinports. Also I already had python on cygwin but not downloaded for windows and I didn't want conflicts.

Comment: I guess you may try to start a X window in cygwin? If that solves your problem, maybe pygame inside cygwin is not an good option for Windows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a cygwin update that seems to require X windows for almost all GUI's, making an X window server solved this issue.

Install X11's `xinit` and `xorg-server` required packages from your cygwin.exe installer.

Follow the instructions here https://x.cygwin.com/ or here https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/setup.html

Comment: Hi Scott, how do you make an x-window with Cygwin? Thanks

Comment: @AndyK Something similar to `startxwin ./yourscript.py` or `startxwin /usr/bin/python yourscript.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment then, skip all that rigamarole of making *nix abstractions map perfectly on Windows and just install the windows versions:

- [Python For 64-bit](http://lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)
- [Pygame for 64-bit Windows](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/python-2.7.2.amd64.msi)

Install should be double-click and go, and you'll be able to `import pygame` right away.