# I get error initializing SDL: No available video device using code compiled in cygwin using mingw

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, mingw, sdl

I am running this in windows, compiled using cygwin and mingw.

Compile Command:

```
g++ sdl.cpp -I"include" -L"lib" -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o test.exe
```

Code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window*win = SDL_CreateWindow("Test",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,1000, 1000, 0);
    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993480/920069

Comment: Just don't use Cygwin? Programs compiled with the plain MinGW don't suffer from this (or you can use just a cygwin-based *shell* with mingw). I'm not sure if cygwin ships non-cygwin compilers, but there is [msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) does.

Answer (score 0):

On Cygwin:

```
g++ sdl.cpp  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o test.exe
```

Run the X server with `startxwin`, open a terminal and

```
./test.exe
```

A black window with a white bar appears.

As you put no handling of events, you need a hard kill to close the program

```
$ ps ax | grep test
    18455   18448   18455      25368  pty3      197609 12:39:35 /tmp/test

$ kill -9 18455
```